# How item of listview adapt the content’s height automatic?

Tags: android, listview

When there are many contents in listview, item’s height can full screen or over the screen. The contents is few, in the screen can display many items. How could item of listview adapt the content’s height automatic?

My item layout：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_item_frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageHead"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wb_head_image"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wb_head_image" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_item_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_item_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_item_frameLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_item_content_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/main_item_pictures"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:scrollbars="none" >
            </GridView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/comment"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/weibo_comment" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/transmit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView4"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/transmit"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/weibo_transmit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/praise"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView3"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/praise"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/weibo_transmit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `listview` adapter code `getView`